# Detecting time when user does nothing

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I am writing an application that is hidden most of the time but sometimes it should pop up on the user's desktop. (It is in cocoa and objective-c)

I don't want to disturb my dear users when they are busy e.g. watching a movie or actively chating with friends etc. I would like that my app pops up only when user is not busy with other work.

So, is there is a way to detect that "free" time?

Thank you very much in advance for all your brilliant ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might take a look at the source for [Growl](http://growl.info/).  It has its notion of an "idle user" which it uses to condition what action to take with regards to posting notifications.  There may be useful code there.

Comment: Yep check the source code for growl, im fairly sure it is publicly accessable.